# Что делать если взломали мой Microsoft аккаунт и оттуда использовали платные сервисы и мне пришёл чек с очень крупной суммой?

Tags: azure, взлом

Я недавно заметил что моим аккаунтом пользовался не только я. Понял что меня взломали, кто-то отправил каким-то людям письма и рассылки через мой аккаунт.

Также, недавно получил письмо с чеком об использовании Azure, и просто был в шоке так как там сумма $380k за месяц июнь. И это всё думаю из-за того что меня взломали, так как я уже давно не пользовался сервисами Azure. Сам я студент, и была бесплатная пробная версия Azure, использовалась она в целях только для обучения. Но когда зашёл на сервисы, их там была куча, похоже взломавший пользовался ими.

За всё это время Microsoft ни разу не оповестил о подозрительных действиях, либо о входе в аккаунт через другие девайсы в других странах.

Уже написал в тех поддержку Microsoft, и на почту филиала в своей стране. Сегодня звонил им по несколько раз, отвечает только автоответчик.

Прошу по скорее помочь мне решить эту проблему, так как с моей карты они собираются снять деньги уже 19.07. Но карту я пока заблокировал на время.

Comment: Ну так, а чего вы боитесь? Карта заблокирована, можете её закрывать и делать новую =)

Comment: А Microsoft потом докапываться не станет? Судебное дело например?

Comment: Если ты из России, то вряд-ли